# Does matter to match furniture built with the same kind of wood?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the kind of wood matter to build furnitures ?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/does-the-kind-of-wood-matter-to-build-furnitures)

will a room be more "attractive" or efficient if all furnitures are built in oak ?
Will a room with furnitures built in different kind of wood matters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of materials on the dwarves is completely individual. There is no room score for that. For those effects, see [my answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/does-the-kind-of-wood-matter-to-build-furnitures/5413#5413).